# Pandas time series group by every 15 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have data in the following format in pandas dataframe. I would like to see the average duration of the event every 30 minutes or 1 hour.

```
id            begin_time                    end_time
499078360    2019-08-30 13:26:04.124235    2019-08-30 13:42:23.680142
499074090    2019-08-30 13:21:57.685308    2019-08-30 13:39:57.993772
499084485    2019-08-30 13:32:11.533709    2019-08-30 13:45:45.307579
499088441    2019-08-30 13:36:06.971633    2019-08-30 13:48:42.160393
499088460    2019-08-30 13:36:07.935704    2019-08-30 13:48:30.037312
```

This is how I got the count of a number of events happening in every 5 minutes.

```
enter_count = df['begin_time'].value_counts()
exit_count = df["end_time"].value_counts()
df2 = pd.concat([enter_count, exit_count], axis=1, keys=["enter", "exit"])
df2.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df2["diff"] = df2["enter"] - df2["exit"]
df2["diff"] = df2["enter"] - df2["exit"]
counts = df2["diff"].resample("5min", how="sum").fillna(0).cumsum()
```

But I intend to get the **average duration of the events** in every 30 minutes or 1-hour window.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Sample response expected:

```
Time window                 Average Time of the event (minutes)
2019-08-30 13:00:00        18:10
2019-08-30 13:30:00        35:00
2019-08-30 14:00:00        17:00
```

This is just a sample response not exactly expected.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Something like this

```
Time window                 Average Time of the event (minutes)
2019-08-30 13:00:00    18:10
2019-08-30 13:30:00    35:00
2019-08-30 14:00:00    17:00
```

This is just a sample response not exactly expected.

Comment: Put it in your question with formatting please.

Comment: done. please check the edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from computing additional column - duration in minutes (expressed as *float*):

```
df['durMin'] = (df.end_time - df.begin_time) / pd.offsets.Minute()
```

For your sample data the result is:

```
          id                 begin_time                   end_time     durMin
0  499078360 2019-08-30 13:26:04.124235 2019-08-30 13:42:23.680142  16.325932
1  499074090 2019-08-30 13:21:57.685308 2019-08-30 13:39:57.993772  18.005141
2  499084485 2019-08-30 13:32:11.533709 2019-08-30 13:45:45.307579  13.562898
3  499088441 2019-08-30 13:36:06.971633 2019-08-30 13:48:42.160393  12.586479
4  499088460 2019-08-30 13:36:07.935704 2019-08-30 13:48:30.037312  12.368360
```

Then, to get the result, run:

```
mt = df.set_index('begin_time').durMin.resample('30min').mean()
```

The result is:

```
begin_time
2019-08-30 13:00:00    17.165536
2019-08-30 13:30:00    12.839246
Freq: 30T, Name: durMin, dtype: float64
```

There is a small difference from your expectation, i.e. you wanted
the result formatted as *mm:ss*, but if you are unhappy about this
detail, you may "reformat" minutes as *float* to your intended format.

You can do it with a single instruction:

```
pd.to_timedelta(mt, unit='m')
```

getting:

```
begin_time
2019-08-30 13:00:00   00:17:09.932185
2019-08-30 13:30:00   00:12:50.354746
Freq: 30T, Name: durMin, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm. Thanks for a quick response.